# CSS: prevent fixed elements from overlapping scrollbar

Tags: css, overflow, fixed

For my application, I'm using react-router to create transitions between pages. The issue is: I would like to make an effect of "window inside window" to make the transition work, but there is a problem. I'm able to creating a stacking context with `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`. In order to make fixed elements stay on top and not scroll with the context, I need another element inside, that would hold overflowing content.

Here is what I tried:

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'content here '.repeat(500)
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.window {
  background: palevioletred;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* I may use absolute position, don't think that
    matters much though */
  position: relative; 
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  background: turquoise;
  color: white;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="root">
    <header>Some content here</header>
    <main id="content"></main>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to somehow make the `.window` element behave like `window` in browser, i.e. display scrollbar when the content overflows and create fixed elements actually fixed while keeping them inside, so that they don't overlap the scrollbar and user can scroll while hovering over them (which is crucial for me).

Basically I want something like this, but using `div`'s somewhere deeper in the DOM tree than inside `body` and keeping the stacking context:

```js
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'content here'.repeat(500)
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0 }

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: palevioletred;
}

header {
  background: turquoise;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main id="content"></main>
</body>
```

Also I don't want to restructure anything outside, I basically want an isolated window inside window. Sounds a bit complicated, and I'm not sure if that's possible at all.

Comment: @04FS, I did google my problem, but none of the answers suit my case. Maybe I should have added more details, but i don't want to restructure anything outside the `.window` and I want to keep the stacking context. Also it's crucial that one is able to scroll the page while hovering over the `.window`

Comment: Then you will probably have to calculate the appropriate width for the header, by determining the actual scrollbar width resp. the remaining width of the .root first. Neither `100%` nor `100vw` alone will help you here - with the mapping between the `html` element and the viewport you'd get the inbuilt "magic" in that regard, but by moving things down to a lower level, that does not apply any more.

Answer (score -1):

```
.window{overflow-y: auto;}
```

1. overflow-y:auto; and overflow-x: auto; can fix such issue.

Comment: If I do this, as `.window` scrolls, all fixed elements inside it will scroll as well, which is not exactly what I want